# Merge 2 dataframes with conditions on datetimes and get the counts for passfails

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes like this

**df1**

```
ID <- c("ID001","ID001","ID002","ID003")
Type <- c("A","A","B","A")
Measurement <- c("Length","Breadth","Length","Length")
When <- c("2016-09-09 06:00:13", "2016-09-19 09:13:10", "2016-10-13 11:45:14", "2016-10-29 11:56:00")

df1 <- data.frame(ID,Type,Measurement,When)
```

**df2**

```
    ID <- c("ID001","ID001","ID001","ID001","ID001",
            "ID002","ID002","ID002","ID002","ID002")
    Type <- c("A","A","A","A","A",
              "B","B","B","B","B")
    Measurement <- c("Length","Length","Length","Length","Length",
                     "Length","Length","Length","Length","Length")
    Datetime <- c("2016-09-09 01:00:13", "2016-09-09 04:00:13", "2016-09-09 09:00:13", "2016-09-09 21:00:13","2016-09-09 23:00:13",
                  "2016-10-13 10:45:14", "2016-10-13 11:15:14", "2016-10-13 11:48:14", "2016-10-13 11:55:14","2016-10-13 21:45:14")
    PassFail <- c("Pass","Fail","Pass","Fail","Pass",
                  "Fail","Fail","Pass","Pass","Pass")

    df2 <- data.frame(ID,Type,Measurement,Datetime,PassFail)
```

I am trying to merge these 2 dataframes to get counts of passes and fails for measurements only for "Datetime" in df2 greater than "WHEN" in df1.

**My desired output is**

```
    ID Type Measurement                When PassCount FailCount
  ID001    A      Length 2016-09-09 06:00:13         2         1
  ID002    B      Length 2016-10-13 11:45:14         3         0
```

I tried using sqldf to get this

```
library(sqldf)
df3<-sqldf("SELECT L.*, r.Datetime, r.PASSFAIL
            FROM df1 as L
            LEFT JOIN df2 as r
            ON L.ID=r.ID
            AND L.Type=r.Type
            AND L.Measurement=r.Measurement
            WHERE r.Datetime > L.When
            ORDER BY L.When")
```

I am being unsuccessful at obtaining the output. Could someone point me in the right direction? I also would like a fast merge solution since I want to apply it to a larger dataset.

Comment: Please use date-time formats, not factors.

Comment: dplyr has functions like left_join, filter, group_by, summarise that should solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With data.table, a non-equi join seems to work:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, When := as.POSIXct(When)]
setDT(df2)[, Datetime := as.POSIXct(Datetime)]

df2[df1, on=.(ID, Datetime > When), if (.N > 0L) as.list(table(PassFail)), by=.EACHI]

#       ID            Datetime Fail Pass
# 1: ID001 2016-09-09 06:00:13    1    2
# 2: ID002 2016-10-13 11:45:14    0    3
```

If you want a row for each row of `df1`, remove the `if` clause.

To add the counts as columns to `df1`:

```
df1[, levels(df2$PassFail) := 
  df2[df1, on=.(ID, Datetime > When), as.list(table(PassFail)), by=.EACHI][, !c("ID","Datetime")]
]
```

Comment: Wonderful solution. It took sometime for me to understand your code but now makes sense. Thank you so much. I just applied it to a bigger dataset and it works like charm.